# Server to amazon EC2 instance communication with python?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, tcp, server-to-server

I have this. But it only works locally. I always receive a connection timeout when I run the client. 
The port on the server is open to the default security group.

server.py:

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print self.client_address
        print self.data
        self.request.send(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 9800
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto('Hello, world\n'('host.ip',  9800))
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client you're using `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` which is **UDP**, yet you are using **TCP** server (which would be `socket.SOCK_STREAM`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're opening port 9800 but talking to port 9999

Comment: Very correct - I incorrectly wrote my example down. I'm very sorry, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The code works correctly.

Within the AWS console within the *Networking and Security* tab select *Security Groups* and within the default security profile under the 'inbound' tab - add your port to the list...

using a source of `0.0.0.0/0` will listen on all ports.